# I am really struggling to run this Nextflow Pipeline

Tags: bioinformatics, nextflow

I want a pipeline that takes inputs like this from a folder called "input" let's say. Files are formatted like so "Gene_KOs1.tsv  Gene_KOs2.tsv  Mutations1.tsv  Mutations2.tsv". My python script will run through each "pair" and produce an output. I would like that output to be put in a folder named Gene_Mutation1 for example as each output file is called the same thing. I thought this was simple but apparently it is not. Here is my current code, unfortunately, it does not save the output csv correctly.

I have tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow nextflow.enable.dsl=2

params.inputDir = "/mnt/scratch-raid/data/l/nextflow_test/input" params.outputDir = "/mnt/scratch-raid/data/l/nextflow_test/output"


workflow {
    inputDir = file(params.inputDir)
    
    // List all gene files
    genesFiles = inputDir.listFiles().findAll { it.name.startsWith('Gene_KOs') }
    
    // List all mutation files
    mutationFiles = inputDir.listFiles().findAll { it.name.startsWith('Mutations') }
    
    // Process each gene file
    genesFiles.each { genesFile ->
        // Extract the number from the gene file name
        def geneNumber = genesFile.name.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "")

        // Find the matching mutation file
        def mutationFile = mutationFiles.find { it.name.contains("Mutations${geneNumber}") }

        if (mutationFile) {
            println "Starting analysis for ${genesFile.name}"

            genesBaseName = genesFile.name.replaceAll("\\.tsv\$", "")
            mutationsBaseName = mutationFile.name.replaceAll("\\.tsv\$", "")
            pairOutputDir = "${params.outputDir}/${genesBaseName}_${mutationsBaseName}"

            // Create the output directory
            file(pairOutputDir).mkdirs()

            // Run your Python script here
            """
            python3 /mnt/scratch-raid/data/l/nextflow_test/Main.py ${genesFile} ${mutationFile} ${pairOutputDir}
            """
            
            println "Finished processing: ${genesFile.name} and ${mutationFile.name}"
        } else {
            println "No matching mutations file found for: ${genesFile.name}"
        }
    }
}
```

I would expect to see the csv's in their respective directories but the directories are empty with no evidence of the python script ever being run

Comment: " Run your Python script here" . Strange, you don't use any `process` keyword here.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Nextflow pipeline. In a Nextflow pipeline, you must have at least one process and the workflow block. You don't have either. I recommend you take our [community foundational nextflow training](https://training.nextflow.io/basic_training).

I haven't tested the code below, but it takes you much closer to what you want. Put the `Main.py` script file in a `bin` folder created in the pipeline folder. This way, Nextflow will stage it regardless of your compute environment. If you're using containers, for example, you would need to guarantee your `Main.py` script is within the container. By putting it in a bin folder, Nextflow will take care of that.

```
params.inputDir = '/mnt/scratch-raid/data/l/nextflow_test/input/'
params.outputDir = '/mnt/scratch-raid/data/l/nextflow_test/output/Gene_Mutation1'

process YOUR_PROCESS_NAME {
  publishDir "$params.outputDir", mode: "copy"

  input:
  tuple val(sample_id), path(files)

  output:
  path "output_folder/"

  script:
  """
  Main.py ${files[0]} ${files[1]} output_folder/
  """
}

workflow {
  Channel
    .fromFilePairs("${params.inputDir}/*{1,2}.tsv",
                   checkIfExists: true)
    | YOUR_PROCESS_NAME

}
```